# getting two navigation bar when clicking tabbar more button

Tags: ios, iphone, uitabbarcontroller, uinavigationbar

Having one main navigation controller in whole application and also one main tabbarcontroller , problem is that when i click om 'more' tab of tabbarcontroller at that time it's showing two navigation bars

to solve this problem i tried to hide my main navigation controllers navigationbar using following code :

```
        self.tabbar.navigationController.navigationBarHidden =YES;
```

but doing this gives me unexpected result in the form of half navigationbar with half black background.

if any one knows the solution then please help me.
thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not usually good UI to have your tab bar controller embedded in a navigation controller. You should rethink your app structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make  viewController With separate UINavigationController,

put this code in Appdelegate

```
ViewController *a = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"a" bundle:nil];
ViewController *b= [[CreateMeetingViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"b" bundle:nil];
ViewController *c = [[SettingsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"c" bundle:nil];


UINavigationController *nav_1 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:a];
UINavigationController *nav_2 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:b];
UINavigationController *nav_3 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:c];

MainTabBar = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
MainTabBar.delegate = self;
[MainTabBar setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:nav_1,nav_2,nav_3,nil]];
MainTabBar.view.frame=self.view.frame;

[self.view addSubview:MainTabBar.view];
```

Comment: @ Jignesh Mayani : thank you so much.. its working fine after creating separate navigation controller for each view controller.

Answer (score 0):

Write in viewWillAppear, i hope it will be helpful for you

```
       [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check your .Xib you check the option Top Bar this should be 'None' in the identity inspector.